# CFTC COT reports

Tags: futures, market-data

Beginner question. As I understand it (vaguely), the COT report contains information on activities (eg. long/short position held) for specific futures contracts. Take, for instance, COT for [13874A](https://www.quandl.com/data/CFTC/13874A_F_ALL-Commitment-of-Traders-E-MINI-S-P-500-STOCK-INDEX-CME-Futures-Only-13874A), the corresponding futures contracts would be the ES (E-Mini S&P 500) future contract.

Now, what about [097741](https://www.quandl.com/data/CFTC/097741_F_ALL-Commitment-of-Traders-JAPANESE-YEN-CME-Futures-Only-097741)? Which are the corresponding futures contract? 6J, J7(e-mini JPY/USD), MJY(Micro JPY/USD)? Or all?

Comment: I don't know a complete list of the CTFC ID's used in COT reports (does any one?). However it does seem that 13874A refers to ES, while 13874+ includes all S&P 500 type contracts on the CME (consolidated S&P500). From the fact that CFTC ID 097741 is described as .CONTRACTS OF JPY 12,500,000 it seems to be the 6J contract https://www.cftc.gov/MarketReports/CommitmentsofTraders/AbouttheCOTReports/cot_about Sorry I don't have a more authoritative answer. Maybe you should ask Quandl or the CFTC.

Answer (score 1):

According to the CFTC COT Report, as below, you can see that the #097741 CFTC code refers to the 12,500,000 contracts of the JPY futures.
[image: CFTC COT]

The same can be found here on the CME website, https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/fx/g10/japanese-yen_contract_specifications.html

So to answer your question, this relates to 6J

Comment: thank you for your answer. So do the numbers in the report correspond to only 6J contracts? What about J7 and MJY? I can't seem to find the COT reports related to them.

Comment: COT report is for institutional buying/selling activity. I doubt, when the regular contract is available, any institution would be looking at trading these mini/micro futures contracts.